# Can $X^*$ characterize smooth norm on $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

I have conjectured following statement in the Banach space $X$ with norm $\|.\|$.

Let $B \subseteq X$ is unit closed ball in $X$ then,

$\|.\|$ is smooth, in sense $\|.\|$ is differentiable at any nonzero point in $X$, if and only if for any point, say $ x_0 \in \text{bd}(B)$ there is a unique $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=f(x_0).$

My thought: I think proving Left $\rightarrow$ Right is easy It is just a separation, and using smoothness of norm we can show that $f\in X^*$ is unique, but I am interested see your rigorous proof.
I don't have any idea about the other way! Even I am not sure it is true! However I am quite positive it is true when $X$ is finite dimension, still any proof in this particular case would be appreciated .
(I first assumed $X$ is a reflexive,(I don't know why I did that! maybe because my unexplainable intuition) anyway you may assume reflexivity)

Thanks for nice comments and answers inadvance!

Comment: Also asked on MO: [Can $X^*$ characterize a smooth norm on $X$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271570)

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about cross-posting; the main suggestion is always to link to other copies of the post. Of course, other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] might be of interest, too.